# If I allow all users in web.config should it still redirect to login?

Tags: asp.net

I'm integrating security into an existing asp classic website. and I'd like to keep the anonymous users able to still access the site until I'm ready to flip the switch. Shouldn't setting allow users="*" let everyone in and not redirect? Right now it's redirecting all pages until you authenticate.

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="foConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=fo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=foSecurity;Password=" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>

  <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>  

        <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
        </authentication>

        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="foSecurityConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/foSecurity"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="foSecurityConnectionString" applicationName="/foSecurity"/>
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="true">
   <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="foSecurityConnectionString" applicationName="/foSecurity"
     name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    <add applicationName="/foSecurity" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
     type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
   </providers>
  </roleManager>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>


    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.asp" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>



</configuration>
```

Comment: AFAIK, you're right, it should... Maybe you have some other rules/configs/settings interfering?

Comment: I've now erased the web.config. and did an iisreset. and instead of rd to the login.aspx page it's giving the authentication pop up asking for username and password. it's like it's stuck from an old configuration or something.

Comment: I got it working. there was another web.config in the /account directory that although had allow all users="*" it also had deny all users. I removed deny all users and it worked.